# Strong typing -> Named type

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm trying to generate a strong(er) type wrapper for C++. I've seen the [`NamedType` by Jonathan Boccara](https://github.com/joboccara/NamedType), but I want a slightly different behavior.

Ideally I would be able to use something like

```cpp
using StrongInt = Named<int, "description here">;
```

But due to limitations of C++ a `const char*` cannot be used directly as a template parameter

I've made the following

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <utility>

template <typename Type, char const *Name> class Named {
public:
  using UnderlyingType = Type;

  constexpr Named() requires std::default_initializable<Type>
  = default;
  explicit constexpr Named(Type const &val) : val_{val} {}
  explicit constexpr Named(Type &&val) : val_{std::move(val)} {}
  explicit constexpr operator Type() const { return val_; }

private:
  Type val_;
};
```

It's quite simple like this. You can use it like

```cpp
static constexpr const char strongIntName[]{"description here"};
using StrongInt = Named<int, strongIntName>;
```

You need to explicitly cast or initialize it to use it, enforcing strong typing. (no implicit dangers)

Doe you gals/guys/etc think I'm missing something essential here?

Comment: In C++20 you can use suitable class types as template arguments.  The idea is to use a static string template class instead of a plain C string literal.  In the past, I'm made static variables holding the strings, and fed those to the template argument.

Comment: For strong types based on built-in integral types (including `char`), I just use a `enum class`.  It gives the same semantics as your empty wrapper class: explicit conversion possible two/from the underlying and the strong type.

Answer (score 6):

## Design review

I’ve been working on something like this for a while now, and I considered a solution similar to what you’re using before ultimately rejecting it. I also went in a different direction than Boccara.

Your current design is annoying to use, because it requires separately defining name strings for the tags. If that were the only problem, I suppose I could live with it… but the *real* problem is a danger that you might end up with strings with the same content nevertheless being “different” because they live at different addresses. Consider your example:

```
static constexpr const char strongIntName[]{"description here"};
using StrongInt = Named<int, strongIntName>;
```

If this is in a header—which is perfectly reasonable—but included in multiple translation units, the address of the string may be different in each translation unit.

Don’t believe me? See for yourself:

- [“Works” in GCC](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CKbw9qKTSFeWuXE1)
- [Fails in Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sVqh6NggNr8YaWqI)

Using the *pointers* to the strings is a sucker’s game. It just won’t work reliably. You want to use *the strings themselves*. For example:

```
template <typename Type, std::array<char, 32> Tag> class Named {
public:
  using UnderlyingType = Type;

  constexpr Named() requires std::default_initializable<Type>
  = default;
  explicit constexpr Named(Type const &val) : val_{val} {}
  explicit constexpr Named(Type &&val) : val_{std::move(val)} {}
  explicit constexpr operator Type() const { return val_; }

private:
  Type val_;
};

static constexpr auto strongIntName = std::array<char, 32>{'f', 'o', 'o'};
using StrongInt = Named<int, strongIntName>;
```

[And now it works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bhbohNtAOokihjGO).

This is still annoying, though, because I still have to define the strong type in two steps (first the name, then the actual type). It’s even uglier now that you have to spell out the string character by character (though you could use `to_array()`).

User defined literals to the rescue:

```
constexpr auto operator"" _tag(char const* s, std::size_t n) -> std::array<char, 32>
{
    auto a = std::array<char, 32>{};

    std::copy_n(s, std::min(n, std::size_t{32}), a.data());

    return a;
}
```

Now you can just do:

```
using StrongInt = Named<int, "foo"_tag>;
```

Now, obviously, you shouldn’t use a naked `std::array` like I did. You should use a proper tag type. Internally that type would just hold a `std::array` of `char`s, though. You don’t necessarily need to use a fixed size, either… but I leave dealing with that as an exercise for the reader. I’m not sure if you’ll be able to get an interface as nice as `Named<int, "str">`—you might be forced to swallow your pride and accept either `Named<int, "str"_tag>` or `Named<int, tag{"str"})`/`Named<int, tag("str"))`. If so, that’s still not bad.

Now, I mentioned that I’d considered this kind of design and rejected it. That’s because I found that it is fairly rare that I *just* want a strongly aliased `T` and *nothing else*. For cases where I do… this is fine (though I’d drop the `explicit` on the conversion operation back to `T`; that just seems pointlessly painful). But… consider, for example, you want to use a strong `int` for a person’s age. With your current design:

```
using age_t = Named<int, "age"_tag>;

auto age = age_t{21};
```

All good, right?

Well, yeah, but… it’s impossible for someone to have a negative age. Wouldn’t it be nice to be able to detect and catch that at compile time? It would completely eliminate a whole class of bugs.

(As an aside, if you’re thinking, “okay then, we’ll just use `unsigned int` instead of `int`”… [no, just no](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-nonnegative).)

The solution I came up with is to use a type as the tag, not just a string. Very basically:

```
template <typename Type, typename Desc>
class Named
{
public:
    using UnderlyingType = Type;

    explicit constexpr Named(Type const &val) : val_{Desc::validate(val)} {}
    explicit constexpr Named(Type &&val) : val_{std::move(Desc::validate(val))} {}

private:
    Type val_;
};

struct age_t_description
{
    static constexpr auto validate(int v)
    {
        if (v < 0)
            throw std::invalid_argument{"age cannot be negative"};

        return v;
    }
};

using age_t = Named<int, age_t_description>;

auto age_1 = age_t{21};
auto age_2 = age_t{-3}; // compile time error
```

Once you start down this road, you discover just how powerful and flexible the description type can be. I’m still exploring and experimenting, but just one example of the kind of thing I’ve explored is default constructiblity. I let the description type decide whether the final type is default constructible in several ways. For example, one possibility is:

1. If the description type has a static member named `default_construct`, then:
   a.  If `default_construct` is `same_as` `Type` then set the internal value to the value of `default_construct` in the default constructor.
   b.  Otherwise, if `default_construct` is invocable and returns a type that `is_convertible` to `Type`, then call that in the default constructor.
   c.  Otherwise, if `default_construct` is `convertible_to` `Type`, use that in the default constructor.
   d.  Otherwise, if `default_construct` is `convertible_to` `bool` and is (compile-time) `true`, then use `= default` as the default constructor.
   e.  Otherwise, compile-time error.
2. Otherwise, the type is not default constructible.

So, (again, very roughly):

```
template <typename T, typename Tag>
class type
{
public:
    constexpr type() noexcept(is_nothrow_default_constructible<T>)
        requires same_as<Tag::default_construct, T>
        : _val{Tag::default_construct}
    {}

    constexpr type() noexcept(is_nothrow_default_constructible<T>)
        requires (not same_as<Tag::default_construct, T>
            and (invocable<Tag::default_construct> and convertible_to<invoke_result_t<Tag::default_construct>, T>))
        : _val{Tag::default_construct()}
    {}

    constexpr type() noexcept(is_nothrow_default_constructible<T>)
        requires (not same_as<Tag::default_construct, T>
            and not (invocable<Tag::default_construct> and convertible_to<invoke_result_t<Tag::default_construct>, T>)
            and (convertible_to<Tag::default_construct, bool> and bool(Tag::default_construct)))
     = default;

private:
    T _val;
};
```

The upshot of this is that you can do:

```
struct age_t_desc
{
    // default constructed age values are always 21
    static constexpr auto default_construct = 21;

    // or:
    // default constructed age values are random between 10 and 100
    static consteval auto default_construct() -> int
    {
        return compile_time_rand_between(10, 100);
    }

    // or:
    // default constructed age values are trivially constructible
    static constexpr auto default_construct = true;
};
```

This is not *that* difficult to implement, but I’ve found that figuring out the rules is *extremely* hard. (For example, what if `T` is `bool`. Should `static constexpr auto default_construct = false;` mean that `type<bool, ...>` is *not* default constructible, or *is* default construcible and defaults to `false`?) I’ve also found numerous other tricky pain points.

Anywho, your design is fine for basic strong aliasing… once you use actual string *values* and not *pointers* as tags.

## Code review

```
template <typename Type, char const *Name> class Named {
```

There’s no need to pack everything on one line like this. At the very least, the class name—literally the most important thing about the class—deserves its own line, so it’s easy to spot.

Also, [putting the type modifier next to the identifier, rather than the type being modified, is C style](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl18-use-c-style-declarator-layout). In other words:

- `char const *Name` ← this is C style
- `char const* Name` ← this is C++ style

So:

```
template <typename Type, char const* Name>
class Named
{
```

That reads far better to me. (You could put the opening brace on the same line as the class name, I suppose, but why? It’s not like you’re hard up for vertical space in a computer.)

```
constexpr Named() requires std::default_initializable<Type>
  = default;
```

Might be worth adding a `noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<Type>)` in there.

```
  explicit constexpr Named(Type const &val) : val_{val} {}
  explicit constexpr Named(Type &&val) : val_{std::move(val)} {}
```

These two lines are really the entire point of the whole class.

At the very least, you should make sure the move constructor is `noexcept` smart, because no-fail moving is *vital* for safe and performant code. While you’re at it, you might as well make the copy constructor `noexcept` smart as well.

But consider what would happen if you have a strong alias string type, that you want to construct with a string view:

```
using strong_string = Named<std::string, "whatever"_tag>;

auto sv = "foo"sv;

auto ss = strong_string{sv};    // won't work: string_view won't implicitly
                                // convert to string.

// you have to do:
auto ss = strong_string{std::string{sv}};

// this happens to work, though:
auto ss = strong_string{"foo"};
// just because std::string has an implicit constructor from char*...
// which is probably not a great idea, but there it is
```

That seems a bit clunky.

If I can construct a `T` from `Args...`, then I can always do:

```
using type = Named<T, "">;

auto t = type{T{args...}};
```

So wouldn’t it be nice if I could just do `auto t = type{args...};`? So long as `sizeof(Args...)` is not 1, this doesn’t seem to risk any accidental implicit conversions. And when `sizeof(Args...)` *is* 1, you can make it explicitly `explicit`.

That would mean this could work:

```
using strong_string = Named<std::string, "whatever"_tag>;

// explicit conversion and construction always works
auto ss1 = strong_string{"str"sv};  // works
auto ss2 = strong_string{"str"};    // also works (as it would anyway)
auto ss3 = strong_string{10, 'x'};  // also works (as it would with std::string)

// implicit conversion never works
auto func(strong_string);

func("str"s);   // nope
func("str"sv);  // nope
func("str");    // nope
func({"str"s}); // nope

// but explict conversion always works, of course
func(strong_string{"str"s});
func(strong_string{"str"sv});
func(strong_string{"str"});

// non-conversion construction can be explicit or not, your choice:
func(strong_string{10, 'x'});   // works
func({10, 'x'});                // *might* work, up to you
```

As you can see, allowing direct construction of the internal value improves usability quite a bit, may improve performance (no need for a temporary that has to be moved), and would even allow aliasing types that are non-copyable and non-movable (because they can be constructed directly in-place via forwarding).

```
explicit constexpr operator Type() const { return val_; }
```

While making conversion *to* the strong aliased type explicit is obviously the whole point of the thing, not sure there’s a good reason to make conversion *from* explicit as well. What is the worst-case scenario of implicit conversion *from* the strong type? There’s no chance that it might implicitly be converted to the underlying type and *back*, because the conversion *back* would be explicit.

Making the conversion *from* explicit just makes working with the type harder. Consider:

```
using mass_t = Named<double, "mass"_tag>;
using speed_t = Named<double, "speed"_tag>;

auto mass = mass_t{1.0};
auto speed = speed_t{5.0};

auto kinetic_energy = 0.5 * double{mass} * std::pow(double{speed}, 2);
// as opposed to:
auto kinetic_energy = 0.5 * mass * std::pow(speed, 2);
```

But it’s even worse, because using `double` explicitly in the casts above is brittle. If you later change the underlying type to `long double`, you’re silently losing precision. You have to do:

```
auto kinetic_energy = 0.5 * mass_t::UnderlyingType{mass} * std::pow(speed_t::UnderlyingType{speed}, 2);
// as opposed to:
auto kinetic_energy = 0.5 * mass * std::pow(speed, 2);
```

And you should really use `decltype(mass)` rather than `mass_t`… *and* you might even need a couple of `typename`s in there, in some contexts.

And consider what you have to do to convert one strong type to another:

```
using temp_c_t = Named<double, "temperature in celsius"_tag>;
using temp_f_t = Named<double, "temperature in fahrenheit"_tag>;


// Celsius and Fahrenheit are the same at -40
auto temp_f = temp_f_t{-40};
auto temp_c = temp_c_t{temp_f_t::UnderlyingType{temp_f}};
// as opposed to:
auto temp_c = temp_c_t{temp_f};
```

I just don’t see a reason to make it difficult to convert *from* the strong alias to the underlying type. I don’t see any way that can introduce bugs.

One thing that’s missing from your strong alias is a way to inspect the underlying value without copying it. Suppose the underlying type is `std::string`, and all I want to do is print it. Currently, I have to do this:

```
using type = Named<std::string, "foo"_tag>;

auto val = type{"data"};

std::cout << std::string{val};  // copy-constructs a temporary string
```

(You could fix the above code by adding an inserter for strongly aliased types, which might be a good idea in general if the type already supports inserting int a stream. But that’s a design decision and beside the point here.)

You could add a member function to access the internal value as a reference, but that would mean the strong alias type’s public interface is different. Say you call that function `value()`… if the underlying type also has a `value()` function, then in generic code, your strong alias type will *look* like the underlying type, but behave differently.

So a better idea might be to add a free, friend function, somewhat like this:

```
template <typename Type, /*...*/ Name>
class Named
{
public:
    // ... [snip] ...

    friend constexpr auto underlying_value(Named const& n) noexcept                     -> Type const& { return n.val_; }
    friend constexpr auto underlying_value(Named&&      n) noexcept(is_nothrow_movable) -> Type        { return std::move(n.val_); }

    // ... [snip] ...
};

using type = Named<std::string, "foo"_tag>;

auto val = type{"data"};

std::cout << underlying_value(val); // no copy or move

// the r-value overload allows this:
auto&& s = underlying_value(type{"foo"});   // no copy, just a move
```

This is still changing the public interface, but is probably safer than adding a new member function.

Comment: Thanks for the very extensive code review: it gave me much insights. I agree your `tag` type is very powerful, but it's over-engineered for my situation. All I want is to have a single strong type. I don't want to implement contracts. Small thing regarding code format: this was done automatically by `clang-format` on save in it's "Google" settings. So according to Google, that's how you should write C++. I don't think you should claim "This is C++" "this is C". Many companies each have their own style guide. Like Bjarne/Herb say on isocpp "this is just a recommendation"

Comment: You're answers actually explained me why Jonathan chose the additional parameter to be `typename Parameter`. I didn't understand it at first, but now I see you can just declare a `struct` in-place. e.g. `using StrongInt = NamedType<int, struct this_is_my_strong_name_type>;`. I misunderstood the readme. So I'm now considering using most of their implementation. With some changes, like more concepts and noexcepts.

Comment: “… you can just declare a `struct` in-place…” That’s not a great idea. It doesn’t work the way you probably think it does, and is brittle, allowing for behaviour to silently change due to code changes far away in the code base. It’s unfortunate that Boccara is promoting this “trick”. Just define the tag struct on one line, then use it.

Comment: some offtop here: IMHO this strong typing shenanigans are no more than XY solution to the problem of an essential language feature like designated parameters. Contraints + designated parameters make strong typing obsolete for most of the use cases. Consider `in_bounds(.latitude = 23, .longitude = 42);` - it is essentally the same as `.in_bounds(latitude{23}, longitude{42});`, but the order doesn't matter, hence the initial reason for strongly typed parameters doesn't exist (you can't confuse them by accident).

Comment: Designated initializers hardly solve all the problems strong types solve (function parameters are not even close to the only concern), and they’re generally not great even for parameter passing because they require constructing a structure in memory, whereas individual items can often be passed in registers. [See for yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/5Whd1Pfvx). Also, if I’m reading your comment correctly, you seem confused: the order *does* matter for designated initializers. (If you want arbitrary ordering with *either* strong types or DI, you *can* get it… with lots of overloading.)